# Reading data file into multidimensional array Java

Tags: java, arrays, datainputstream

I have a .dat file that I want to load into a custom array.  How do I get it to actually load the data into the array.  The data consists of a (String, int, int, double, String).

```
class CDinventoryItem{


   private CDinventoryItem [] inven = new CDinventoryItem[1000];


    public CDinventoryItem (String title, int itemNumber, int numberofUnits, 
    double unitPrice, String genre){

              DataInputStream input;

            try{

                input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream("inventory.dat"));

                inven = input.read(CDinventoryItem[]);  //line I am receiving error on


            }
            catch ( IOException error ){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "File not found",
                "" ,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }


        }

}
```

So now readFile is in its own class...

```
class readFile {
public CDinventoryItem[] inven;

    public readFile(){

BufferedReader in = null;

try {
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.dat"));
    String line = null;
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        // process each line
        String[] parts = line.split(",");
        String title = parts[0];
        int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int numberofUnits = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
        double unitPrice = Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
        String genre = parts[4];

        CDinventoryItem item = new CDinventoryItem(title, itemNumber, numberofUnits, 
unitPrice, genre);

        //add item to array
        inven[i] = item;
        i++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}}
```

and I am calling it from my CDinventory class

```
        readFile invenItem = new readFile();
        list = new JList(invenItem.inven);
```

but it gives me a: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
on line:
    readFile invenItem = new readFile();

Doesn't seem to like me passing the array that way.

Comment: I don't understand the question. It sounds like you want a 1-dimensional array of `CDinventoryItem`.

Comment: Sorry maybe I am misunderstanding.  I just want to take the contents of the .dat and load it into my CDinventoryItem array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file line by line. Split each line on `,` and create a single CDInventoryItem. Add the item to your array.

Also, note that this method should not be in the constructor of `CDInventoryItem`. Your `CDInventoryItem` class should not even have an array of `CDInventoryItem`s. All this should be done in a separate class.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
public void readFile() {

    BufferedReader in = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.dat"));
        String line = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

            // process each line
            String[] parts = line.split(",");
            String title = parts[0];
            int itemNumber = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
            int numberOfUnits = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            double unitPrice = Double.parseDouble(parts[3]);
            String genre = parts[4];

            CDinventoryItem item = new CDinventoryItem(title, itemNumber, unitPrice, genre);

            //add item to array
            inven[i] = item;
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: dogbane is correct. If you want to read in fully formed objects, you may want to consider object serialization in Java: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you that worked.  And I should just call this method with a new readFile();?

Comment: See this is where Java loses me.  Why shouldn't the array CDinventoryItem be in the class CDinventoryItem?

Comment: @user569127 because that wouldn't be object oriented programming. A CDInventory item has a name, genre, price etc, but an array of CDInventoryItems? That doesn't make sense. You should have a separate class called CDInventory which contains an array of CDInventoryItems.

Comment: OK, nevermind.  I created a new class within my main called class readFile;  And removed my array CDinventoryItem from my CDinventoryItem class.  Gonna refactor my class CDinventoryItem to CDinventory

Comment: OMG, that just wiped out everything I have written.  A week solid of work down the drain...

Comment: OK, I created a separate class for the readFile. In my CDinventoryItem class I am calling this new class.  Adding code above...

Comment: I am getting the Exception error because I am parsing the ints.  When they are saved as ints already.

Comment: The reason why you are getting the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, is because you have not initialised the array! You need to do: `inven = new CDInventoryItem[1000]` in the constructor of your readFile class. You can't add items to an array without initialising it first.